# Question regarding PMBOK (6th edition) definitions of project life cycles

Tags: pmp

I am currently studying for the PMI PMP exam and stumbled upon the following question in Kim Heldman's "[Project Management Professional Practice Tests](https://www.worldcat.org/title/pmp-project-management-professional-exam-practice-tests/oclc/1064940226)" book (correct answer boldened):

> A project manager performing Closing activities is currently focused on
> addressing the highest business value items first. What life cycle is she using to
> deliver her project?
>
> A. Highly predictive
>
> B. Adaptive
>
> **C. Highly adaptive**
>
> D. Waterfall

My answer was "adaptive" since "highly adaptive" meant nothing to me.
I searched the PMBOK, 6th edition, and could not find any mention of "highly" adaptive vs. "adaptive", or "highly" predictive. Only "adaptive" and "predictive" are mentioned.
Unfortunately, the answer in the book itself does not reference the PMBOK or Heldman's Study Guide.

Is this an occasion where the PMBOK differs from the actual PMP exam content, and the given answer can be considered correct, or should I disregard this question?

Comment: There are horrendous PMP practice question sites out there.  PMI does not share its question bank to anyone so the questions are made up and many are meeting market demand with poor quality materiel.  There are names out there that have a great reputation, such as Rita Mulchahey (sp??).  I'd advise sticking to the known reputable ones.

Comment: My comment above is not meant to be in judgment of the OP's source of the question.  I have no idea who that person is or the quality of her material.

Comment: I agree David, I have tried various resources including Rita's book and online resources, and the quality differences are huge. Although I assumed Kim Heldman to be one of the more reliable resources, hence my question.

Comment: Go to appendix X3.  Page 665.

Comment: Dunno ... this sure feels like "just a bad question" to me.  I say: there shouldn't be two answers that differ only by an adjective.  And, if you really do have to go to "appendix blah, page blah-blah" to find the "correct" answer ... yeah.  Bad question.  *("Writing good tests" is a LOT harder than it looks!)*

Comment: @DavidEspina Thanks for pointing me to the appendix, where the term "highly predictive" is mentioned. I had not thought about the appendix to be honest. You could turn this into an answer to this question, if you'd like.
Regarding the exam question itself, I will still file it under "bad phrasing" since the appendix doesn't seem to distinguish between "highly adaptive" and "adaptive" and calls both "agile" life cycles.

Comment: The appendix does talk about adaptive and mentions the process groups. Read further down.

Comment: Why are there close votes on this question?

Comment: I voted to close because answers to this question are useful only in the context of that particular exam prep reference.  Answers to this question are not useful to the practice of project management.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I think this is not the best question, adaptive and highly adaptive life cycles are discussed in appendix X3 of the PMBoK, 6th Edition.

Answer (score 0):

David Espina has **correctly identified** the Project Management Body of Knowledge Guide reference which answers this question.

As a PMP Exam Prep trainer, I will say this type of question is an outlier. While the exam is as much a reading comprehension exam as it is a project management knowledge exam, **the majority of questions are not like the one you posted**.

Another good resource for lifecycles, especially Agile lifecycles, is the **Agile Practice Guide**. Now, there is not a single question on the PMP Exam from the Agile Practice Guide, but the guide is great at explaining Agile lifecycles and how scope is managed in the Agile world.